# XSS: What type of text encoding is this?

Tags: xss, encoding

I found this encoding as a XSS example to bypass certain filters.

Been trying to look some information (plus encoder/decoder tool) about this type of encoding but was pretty difficult without knowing it's name:

```
xCpl \x3d 1 \x2f \x281 - xBeta \x2a xP\x29\x3b\x0avar xDens \x3d xStdDens \x2a xCtl \x2a xCpl \x2f
```

Comment: It looks like a printer control language. \x appears to indicate a 2 digit hex encoded byte follows. It does not appear to be PCL or ESC/P, however.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about security. Also, there is not enough information: where did you find that text? **If you explain the context where you found that text**, your may be able to get help on [reverseengineering.se].

Comment: Then again, after resolving the hexadecimal escapes, this is `xCpl = 1 / (1 - xBeta * xP);
var xDens = xStdDens * xCtl * xCpl /`. So it's presumably a bit of very lightly obfuscated JavaScript.

Comment: I found this as a XSS example. It's supposed to be encoded JavaScript to pass certain filters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `\x` is indicating that there is going to be an ascii character encoded in hexidecimal.

```
xCpl \x3d 1

\x3d => '='
```

You can use a site like this to decode it individually: http://www.dolcevie.com/js/converter.html

Or, for this example, just put this in a js console:

```
console.log('xCpl \x3d 1 \x2f \x281 - xBeta \x2a xP\x29\x3b\x0avar xDens \x3d xStdDens \x2a xCtl \x2a xCpl \x2f')
```

and you'll get:

```
xCpl = 1 / (1 - xBeta * xP);
var xDens = xStdDens * xCtl * xCpl /
```

It may be used for xss so that it can hide characters that a particularly weak filter wouldn't catch.